# How to access webpack generated filenames in a plugin?

Tags: nginx, webpack

So, here is my situation. I have a JavaScript application where I'm appending the hashes to the filenames, as is the standard for Webpack output. This way the content can be safely cached by the browser, with the fresh load controlled by the changing file hash.

My problem is I have a situation where I need other applications to access mine, and they won't be able to be updated every time the hash changes. So I need a request like this:

https://my-domain.com/assets/js/app.js

to be redirected to

https://my-domain.com/assets/js/app.ab12cd34.js

My application currently uses nginx to serve up the pages, but nginx is static. I don't know how to configure it to dynamically identify the hashed file name and return it.

The app is being deployed to a Pivotal CloudFoundry environment. PCF supports evaluating dynamic Ruby code in an nginx.conf file, so that seemed like an easy way around this. Unfortunately, my company requires that the nginx.conf go through a special parser to enforce security headers. This parser only knows nginx syntax, and mangles any Ruby code there.

So, that leaves me with Webpack. I started investigating ways for Webpack to modify files during the build process, and I discovered the transform() function in the copy-webpack-plugin. It has the ability to modify the files exactly how I need. What is still a challenge, though, is getting the hash filename.

So, I'm hoping there's some way to gain access to what the hash filename will be in this plugin, so that I can inject it into the nginx.conf.

Alternatively, if someone knows another way to get around my core problem, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [webpack-manifest-plugin](https://github.com/danethurber/webpack-manifest-plugin) to create a manifest file with a filename `->` chunkname/bundlename mapping.

This manifest file can then be consumed by any piece of software that needs it.